# How to build and send hex commands to TV

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have an NEC PX-42VM5HA plasma tv that I am trying to control with the connected computer.  I have the data sheet that shows all the codes to control the tv and the protocol information.  I am unsure how to build the right data structure in python to send the HEX control codes.  Below is the Power Control Codes and the Communications Protocol.

```
Communication Protocol:
    Interface: RS-232C
    Communication: Asynchronous
    Baud Rate: 9600
    Data Length: 8bits
    Parity: Odd
    Stop Bit: 1bit
    Communication Code: Hex

Power Control Codes
    ON          9FH 80H 60H 4EH 00H CDH
    OFF         9FH 80H 60H 4FH 00H CEH
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(
    port='COM1',
    baudrate=9600,
    parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

ser.close()
ser.open()
ser.isOpen()

ON=bytearray([0x9FH,0x80H,0x60H,0x4EH,0x00H,0xCDH])
OFF=bytearray([0x9FH,0x80H,0x60H,0x4FH,0x00H,0xCEH])

ser.write(OFF)
time.sleep(30)
ser.write(ON)
ser.close()
```

Comment: You need to drop those `H` characters, they are not valid in hexadecimal integer notation in python.

Answer (score 5):

Write out the control codes as strings

```
ON = "\x9f\x80\x60\x4e\x00\xcd"
ser.write(ON)
```