# Python send hex data via serial port

Tags: python, regex, serial-port

I'm currently working on a small interface that communicates with an FPGA via serial port. It works quite fine, but the data i get is a string e.g. '00CCEE' which has to be interpreted as hex values so 00CCEE is 0x00CCEE.

I read here([How to build and send hex commands to TV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026329/how-to-build-and-send-hex-commands-to-tv)) that you can simply rewrite your string as hex like this:
\x00\xCC\xEE

I did this with a regex:

```
plainText = re.sub("(.{2})", "\\x\\1", plainText, 0, re.DOTALL)
```

Now i'm sending this string to the device:

```
\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF
```

This should be 16 Bytes, but ser.write() returns 64. Meaning that it wrote 64 Bytes(each character in the stirng as a byte) instead of interpreting it as a hex value.

Here is the corresponding piece of code

```
plainText = re.sub("(.{2})", "\\x\\1", plainText, 0, re.DOTALL)

print ser.isOpen()

print plainText
AmountPlain = ser.write(plainText)
print AmountPlain
```

And the Output then is

```
\x00\x11\x22\x33\x44\x55\x66\x77\x88\x99\xAA\xBB\xCC\xDD\xEE\xFF
True
64
```

Any clues?

Comment: `\xHH` is a *string literal notaion*; it is helpful to create a string, not for converting hexadecimal characters to bytes. I duped you to a canonical post that discusses your options.

Comment: Thanks. Did not found this post during my search -.-. Thanks again. That helped.